# Clamping rotated camera in Three.js

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, camera, geometry

In Three.js, I have a 3D scene that contains a floor and an *orthographic* camera.

I have it set up so that the user can move the camera around the scene with their mouse. I want to limit the camera's movement to the dimensions of the floor.

I got it working if the camera is rotated to -90 deg on the x-axis, i.e. if the camera is looking straight down at the floor from above.

But changing the camera to any other angle causes issues with the clamp limits. For example, if I change the camera angle to -40 instead, I can pan further up and down than I should be able to, and hence see parts of the scene that I should not be able to.

How can I integrate the camera's rotation into my below solution?

```js
// Create camera
this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(...);
this.camera.rotation.x = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(-90);

// The size of the floor
const modelBoundingBoxWidth = 14;
const modelBoundingBoxHeight = 14;

// The limits for the camera (in world units)
const cameraLimits = {
    left: -modelBoundingBoxWidth / 2,
    right: modelBoundingBoxWidth / 2,
    top: - modelBoundingBoxHeight / 2,
    bottom: modelBoundingBoxHeight / 2,
};

// Calculate the camera's new position due to the mouse pan
// (...)

// Apply the camera limits to the new camera position
if ((cameraPosNew.x - cameraHalfWidth) < cameraLimits.left) {
    cameraPosNew.x = cameraLimits.left + cameraHalfWidth;
}
else if ((cameraPosNew.x + cameraHalfWidth) > cameraLimits.right) {
    cameraPosNew.x = cameraLimits.right - cameraHalfWidth;
}
if ((cameraPosNew.z - cameraHalfHeight) < cameraLimits.top) {
    cameraPosNew.z = cameraLimits.top + cameraHalfHeight;
}
else if ((cameraPosNew.z + cameraHalfHeight) > cameraLimits.bottom) {
    cameraPosNew.z = cameraLimits.bottom - cameraHalfHeight;
}

// Move the camera to the new position
this.camera.position.set(
    cameraPosNew.x,
    cameraPosNew.y,
    cameraPosNew.z
);
```

I believe I need to project the floor's vertical length onto the camera's vertical length using the camera's rotation angle, so that I can determine how much I need to reduce the vertical clamp limits by (due to the rotation). But I don't know where to start regarding the math. I tried various dot product / vector projection approaches but didn't get anywhere.

I also noticed that at an angle of -40, the space above and below the floor is not equal, meaning either the top and bottom clamp limits need to be different, or perhaps I need to move the camera back by some value (due to the rotation)?

Also note that due to the rotation to -40, I can see more of the scene than I could at -90.

---

**Update**: I think this question is a little unclear, due to me bringing panning into it when I think I need to first improve my understanding of how to calculate what the camera sees when rotated. I have created a separate question for specifically that: [How does rotation influence an orthographic camera in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075181/how-does-rotation-influence-an-orthographic-camera-in-three-js)

Comment: Even at -90 deg, it seems that one has to factor in `y` (the height above the floor) to determine the bounding box.  Eg, a `y` value close to the floor results in a small viewport of the scene requiring greater motion of the camera to traverse the complete floor, whereas a large `y` value allows the camera to see a larger portion of the project in the viewport, and therefore the `x` & `z` bounding box will be much smaller, no?...

Comment: What you explained applies to a perspective camera, but not to an orthographic camera.

Comment: Not quite sure I agree with your response, but it could be due to my misunderstanding of the question.  Even the [orthographic ThreeJS example](https://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_orthographic) shows the ability to increase / decrease the distance from objects in the scene, which in turn affects the scope of the scene that the camera "sees" (ie, the clipping planes / bounding box)...

Comment: The example you're linking to does so using the camera's `zoom` property via the `OrbitControls`, not by changing the camera's `y` position.

Comment: With an orthographic camera, anything in the camera's frustum gets rendered at the same size, independently of its distance from the camera - as long as it is in between the near and far clipping planes.

Comment: That means that for the case where the camera is at -90deg, i.e. is looking directly down at the plane, the `y` position does not matter. However, I do agree that when the camera is rotated to -40deg, `y` position does matter because it now influences which portion of the scene are in the camera's frustum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to simply clamp the position vector, you could [use the `THREE.Vector3.clamp()` method](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.clamp).

```
const boxMin = new THREE.Vector3(-7, 0, -7);
const boxMax = new THREE.Vector3(7, 100, 7);

// Calculate the camera's new position due to the mouse pan
// (...)

// Perform clamping so it doesn't go outside box
cameraPosNew.clamp(boxMin, boxMax);

this.camera.position.copy(cameraPosNew);
```

You're not showing how the rotations are affecting the position within this box, but if you still have to take rotations into consideration to calculate the min/max box bounds, you might need to do some manual calculations with some [basic trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions).

Comment: The question is how to take into account the camera rotation when doing the clamp.

Comment: Then I must be confused. `camera.position` should not be affected when you make changes to `camera.rotation.x`  You should elaborate with [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).